# How to scrape many children down from a common tag with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use BeautifulSoup to access thesaurus.com in order to quickly find synonyms for certain words. However, the synonyms are in a list that has different ids and classes per word, and so the best thing I can do is access a grandparent that is the same per word: Here is a simplified example:

```
<div data-testid="same_between_words">
    <ul class="different_between_words">
        <li>
            <a data-linkid="same_between_words_2">Word 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a data-linkid="same_between_words_2">Word 2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

There's also similar words which are fine to include if necessary and antonyms which are obviously not fine to include. In case it matters, the words do have the same data-linkid between each other and different words but they're also the same as antonyms, so I haven't gotten that to work. My current code is

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/EXAMPLE WORD"
page = requests.get(url)
html = page.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
ele = soup.find('div', attrs={'data-testid': 'word-grid-container'})
syn = ele.findChildren('ul', recursive=False)
print(syn)
```

which gives all of the html for the data-testid in a big old mess, and adding .text doesn't seem to work since it's saying I'm treating a list of results like a single one (which I don't think I am. I'm not using find_all). Not to mention I think adding that would just give me the first synonym which isn't ideal.

I'd like to get a list of synonyms from a word. I've gotten a big single string with all the words but I would love to have it be in a list I can work with since some synonyms have spaces in them (like 'fine and dandy' for 'good'. I can't split a string based on spaces then).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are near to your goal, but to give you an idea, try to select by static things id or HTML structure, may use [`css selectors`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) for convenience.

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/idea"
page = requests.get(url)
html = page.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
print([e.get_text(strip=True) for e in soup.select('#meanings ul li>a')])
```

##### Output

```
['belief', 'concept', 'conclusion', 'design', 'feeling', 'form', 'intention', 'interpretation', 'meaning', 'notion', 'objective', 'opinion', 'perception', 'plan', 'scheme', 'sense', 'solution', 'suggestion', 'theory', 'thought', 'understanding', 'view', 'aim', 'approximation', 'brainstorm', 'clue', 'conception', 'conviction', 'doctrine', 'end', 'essence', 'estimate', 'fancy', 'flash', 'guess', 'hint', 'hypothesis', 'import', 'impression', 'inkling', 'intimation', 'judgment', 'object', 'pattern', 'purpose', 'reason', 'significance', 'suspicion', 'teaching', 'viewpoint', 'believed abstraction']
```

Answer (score 1):

Each word is in `a` tag with `font-weight="inherit"` property, you can even just select all `a` tags.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/smile"
page = requests.get(url)
html = page.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
#words = soup.select_one('div[data-testid="word-grid-container"]').select('a[font-weight="inherit"]')
words = soup.select_one('div[data-testid="word-grid-container"]').select('a')
for word in words:
    print(word.get_text())
```